# Objective C - Excluding imports when on simulator

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way I tell my code to import certain libraries only when it is being compiled to a device?

Something like this in the .h file

```
if (device) {
    #import "Lib1.h"
}
```

Having issue compiling to a simulator with that specific class but works on a device.

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to check whether or not TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR is true during compilation.

```
#if !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)
#import "Lib1.h"
#endif
```